# JSON parsing issues are giving me a 'Cannot read property of undefined' error.

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm working on cloud code that pings eBay, returns JSON, parses it, and stores the top two categories into an array. The parameters sent to eBay are based on what a user types into itemSearch bar the iOS app. When I attempt to send a query like "iPhone", it gives this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findItemsByKeywordsResponse' of undefined
    at Object.Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.success (main.js:37:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:565:19) (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.18)
```

Here is my objective-c code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.nextButton) return;
    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {

        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {

                                            NSLog(@"Successfully pinged eBay!");
                                        }

                                    }];


    }

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

}
```

The cloud code (main.js) running on Parse:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("eBayCategorySearch", function(request, response) {
          url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: url,
      params: {     
       'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords', 
       'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
       'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
       'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
       'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
       'itemFilter(0).name=ListingType' : 'itemFilter(0).value=FixedPrice',
       'keywords' : request.params.item,

        // your other params
     },
      success: function (httpResponse) {


          var response = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text)  

          // count number of times each unique primaryCategory shows up (based on categoryId), return top two (done with a for loop?)

          var userCategories = {};


          var data = httpResponse.data
          data.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.searchResult[0].item.forEach(function(item) 
          {
          var id = item.primaryCategory[0].categoryId;
          if (userCategories[id]) userCategories[id]++;
          else userCategories[id] = 1;
          });

          var top2 = Object.keys(userCategories).sort(function(a, b) 
            {return userCategories[b]-userCategories[a]; }).slice(0, 2);
          console.log('Top two categories: ' + top2.join(', '));


          response.success(httpResponse.data)

          // if user has criteria info for one of the categories already, default to that, send to matchcenter

          // if user has criteria for both categories, ask which one, default to selected categories criteria, send to matchcenter

          // if user has no criteria for either category, redirect to criteriaViewController, save the criteria user inputs, send to matchcenter



      // deal with success and respond to query
  },
            error: function (httpResponse) {
                console.log('error!!!');
                console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            }
       });
});
```

The JSON usually looks like this when returned:

```
{
   "findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[
      {
         "ack":[
            "Success"
         ],
         "version":[
            "1.12.0"
         ],
         "timestamp":[
            "2014-03-26T18:29:40.583Z"
         ],
         "searchResult":[
            {
               "@count":"100",
               "item":[
                  {
                     "itemId":[
                        "151258132867"
                     ],
                     "title":[
                        "Apple iPhone 4 - clean esn - Black (Verizon) Smartphone"
                     ],
                     "globalId":[
                        "EBAY-US"
                     ],
                     "primaryCategory":[
                        {
                           "categoryId":[
                              "9355"
                           ],
                           "categoryName":[
                              "Cell Phones & Smartphones"
```

I don't think it's  being returned properly, hence its inability to find "findItemsByKeywordsResponse". Is there a way I can print out the JSON being returned, to see whether I'm parsing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing your response:

```
var response = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text)
```

But after that you don't use it. You work instead with `httpResponse.data`.

So try using your `response` object:

```
response.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.searchResult[0]......
```

Comment: Doing that still gives me errors that findItemsByKeywordsResponse, searchResult, and item are undefined. I think maybe the JSON isn't being returned properly.